# Developing Online multiplayer management game

Tags: browser, text, multiplayer

I wish to create a college project on a simple online multiplayer management game which will involve players setting orders for the day/week and then obtaining profits. Being a relative beginner I am unable to figure out the architecture required for this task.

As far as I am concerned I would be needing the following things:

- A text interface to display the status of ongoing events and to set orders in a web    browser.

  A certain application that would calculate the results every minute and update the database.

  A database

Sorry for being so newbish, but any advice or links or books on how to proceed will do.

Please comment if any more information is required.

Comment: I have no clue why this would be downvoted; it's a good question.

Comment: thanks....I was getting concerned.....

Comment: do you have experience with php/asp/css/html/sql at all?

Comment: Yes.i have done programming in java/c++/c# and php/mysql. I dont know asp much... but it wont be hard to learn.

Comment: I have to say one thing: use lua for your web code. I've heard horrible things about PHP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/defend-php-convince-me-it-isnt-horrible), and lua is great. Plenty readable and has a good web framework i think (Kepler).

Comment: It's at http://www.lua.org and http://luaforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to run updates every minute?  Are people going to be updating it that often, if they are making orders for a day or week?

I would start with deciding on the equations that will be used in your model.

Then, that will help decide what you need in the database, to give the parameters to the model.

Then, once you have the database, you need to get information from the user, so decide what you need from the user.

For example you should have some random event that will make certain items go up or down in demand, or have resources become more common.

So, you may want to have information in the database that lists what each product is composed of.

If the model will have external information, or, if it is based on what others make, so, for example, last week shoes were not produced, so those that made shoes made a profit. This week everyone is making shoes, so there is too many, so the price went down.

This is why I think starting with your model, and testing your assumptions is the first step.

Any language, system, database will work well, just do what you feel comfy with. When you design the UI, do you want it to look fine on iphones and the Blackberry Razor?  Then that will have a big impact on how you design the UI.

Comment: I have worked out the logic part i.e. all the conditions that should occur (Actually I have made  use case and activity diagrams). But I am finding it difficult to implement because of my relative inexperience in web programming. so any advice regarding that?? See it is a railway manager game in which I need to update the position of train every minute. And orders to be set just before the train leaves.

Comment: If you write it in ASP.NET or Java (JSP and servlets) then you can have a singleton class that will sleep for 60 seconds then execute and back to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Any programming language would be fine.  Pick a lang / arch you or someone in your group are familiar with.  I'm mostly a PHP/ZF, Linux, Postgres guy.  So I would...

Write a little ZendFramework app to collect your user's data and save to postgres database.  I'd host it on a little Linux server.  I like slicehost.com $20/mon, but there are cheaper.  Or make friends with someone with a server.

Then for the update of the orders, use a cron job to run every minute.  If the update process is complex, use another PHP script, else just straight SQL.